# Build hierarchy based on group by column - pyspark or pandas

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I have dataframe

```
|empid|mgrid|deptid|
|-----|-----|------|
|1    |2    |1     |
|2    |3    |1     |
|5    |6    |1     |
|2    |3    |2     |
|3    |4    |2     |
|-----|-----|------|
```

Expected Output

```
|deptid|empid|hierarchy|
|------|-----|---------|
|1     |1    |[2,3]    |
|1     |2    |[3]      |
|1     |5    |[6]      |
|2     |2    |[3,4]    |
|2     |3    |4        |
|------|-----|---------|
```

My Problem - I want to build the hierarchy based on deptid.
I am using the below code to build, but its not based on any column. It takes all.

```
import pandas as pd 
def walk(df, id, f, r, prev=pd.Series(dtype="int64")):
    mgr = df.loc[df[f]==id,][r]
    if not mgr.isna().all():
        prev = walk(df, mgr.tolist()[0], f, r, prev)
    return pd.concat([mgr, prev])
```

Trying something like

```
df_pandas = df_pandas[["deptid","empid","mgrid"]]
df_pandas1 = (df_pandas.groupby("deptid"))
df_pandas1.assign(parent_lineage=lambda x: x["empid"].apply(lambda e: (walk(x, e, "empid", "mgrid")
                                                     .dropna().astype("string").tolist()))
```

Comment: The logic is unclear, can you break down the hierarchy? What are the parent/child here?

Comment: parent lineage is getting build by that function. If you take empid, and mgrId , the function will give you the lineage. But, I want to do the lineage, adding condition that, hierarchy should be build only based on every dept id.

Comment: can you update the previous comment adding the column names to make the numbers non-ambiguous? (i.e. 1/2/3 are which 1/2/3?)

Comment: Not allowing me to edit, so here is the updated comment -    To answer your question , for deptid- 1,   ( empid 1 is having parent -mgrid- 2. Again, empid- 2 is having parent - mgrid -3).    Now , for deptid -2, empid 2 having mgrid 3, and empid 3 having mgrid 4.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it wasn't obvious that "deptid" were just groups (could have been A/B) and not nodes in the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a graph problem, I would use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org) to solve it:

```
import networkx as nx

def get_descendents(g):
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(g, source='empid', target='mgrid',
                                create_using=nx.DiGraph)
    return g['empid'].map(lambda n: list(nx.descendants(G, n)))

df['hierarchy'] = df.groupby('deptid', group_keys=False).apply(get_descendents)
```

Output:

```
   empid  mgrid  deptid hierarchy
0      1      2       1    [2, 3]
1      2      3       1       [3]
2      5      6       1       [6]
3      2      3       2    [3, 4]
4      3      4       2       [4]
```

Your subgraphs:

deptid 1:

[image]

deptid 2:

[image]